# Flow - Update Probability Data Type (Percent(3, 0))

Tags: visual-workflow, formula

I am trying to set the Opportunity Probability standard field within a flow. I am using a formula field to do so. The Formula is the below however I am getting an error of this:

We can't save this record because the “Update Opportunity” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. This error occurred when the flow tried to update records: INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD: Probability (%): value not of required type: 36. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide. Error ID: 459277345-197934 (1432673028)ok up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide. Error ID: 459277345-197934 (1432673028)

From the data type it appears that it whats a whole number.

So if Buy__c is 90 and Buy_goo__c is 40 it should work out to 36. How do you set the standard field Probability?

```
VALUE(TEXT(VALUE(TRIM(LEFT(TEXT({!$Record.Buy__c}),3)))/100 * VALUE(TRIM(LEFT(TEXT({!$Record.Buy_Goo__c}),3)))/100)) * 100
```

Data Stored in Buy and Goo

```
Buy
100% - Funding is secured
90 % - Funding is Extremely Likely
75 % - Funding is Likely
50 % - Funding is Uncertain
25 % - Funding is Unlikely
10 % - Funding is Extremely Unlikely

Goo
100% - Wants Goo, No Doubt
75 % - Favors Goo, but some Detractors
60 % - Biased Slightly Toward Goo
40 % - Biased Slightly Against Goo
25 % - Undecided, Strong Competition
```

Comment: Can you post what kinds of data are stored in Buy__c and Buy_Goo__c?

Comment: Added to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percents need to be between 0 and 1.0 for the Probability field

- `Buy__c` : You are extracting 90, dividing by 100 to get 0.90
- `Buy_Goo__c` : You are extracting 40, dividing by 100 to get 0.40
- Then multiplying to get 0.36 and then
- Multiplying by 100 to get `36`

Skip the final multiply by 100